# How to validate textfield string in iphone?

Tags: iphone

i want to validate string for following condition

1.string  contain  characters only.
2.string don't allow space,enterkey and special characters.

Answer (score 1):

To validate characters only you can use this code

```
NSString *trimmed3 = [textfield.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
BOOL isNumeric = [trimmed3 length] >0 && [trimmed3 rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonNumberSet].location== NSNotFound; 

if (!isNumeric) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"oops"
                                                    message:@"Phone no should be numeric" 
                                                   delegate: self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle: @"Continue"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Comment: Please format your content before posting. It will help everyone - now or in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For condition 1:

```
#define REG_EX_USERNAME_VALIDATION @"[a-zA-Z\\d]"
NSPredicate *userNameValidation = [ NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", REG_EX_USERNAME_VALIDATION];
int retVal  = [ userNameValidation evaluateWithObject:inPasskey];
```

For Condition 2: You can use this delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
// checking for any whitespaces
if(([string rangeOfString:@" "].location != NSNotFound))
{
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```